# N-Body Solver using C with MPI and OpenMP: performance issues with multiple threads due to communication between processes

Tags: c, multithreading, mpi, openmp, distributed-computing

My N-body solver runs great when I use multiple processes and one thread or multiple threads and one process, but it suffers from serious performance issues due to proccess-communication when I use multiple processes AND multiple threads.

I have narrowed down the performance issues and marked them in the code below. There are a couple of key findings I have made already:

1. Even if MPI_Sendrecv_replace is called outside of a omp parallel block the issues still persist.
2. Using MPI_Ssend and MPI_Recv instead of MPI_Sendrecv doesn't help
3. Everything else in my code works perfectly, so don't worry about variables that have not been assigned a value within my code snippet.

*Edit
I am running my code on an HPC cluster at my school that doesn't have any MPI performance analysis tools.

MPI version: 1.6.2

System hardware info listed at: http://acs.kennesaw.edu/services/hpcnodes.php

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (perforamnce issue at line 87):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
double local_start, local_finish, local_elapsed, elapsed, test_start, test_finish, test_elapsed, test_final, t_delta;
int required, provided, my_rank, comm_sz, i, phase, thread_count, num_approximations, num_particles, 
    local_num_particles, dimensions, send_to, recv_from;
char *ptr;

required = MPI_THREAD_SINGLE;
MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, required, &provided); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

thread_count = strtol(argv[1], &ptr, 10);
num_particles = strtol(argv[2], &ptr, 10);
t_delta = strtod(argv[3], &ptr);
num_approximations = strtol(argv[4], &ptr, 10);

local_num_particles = num_particles/comm_sz;
float *temp_forces_positions = malloc(2 * dimensions * local_num_particles * sizeof(float));
for(i = 0; i < 2 * dimensions * local_num_particles; i++)
    temp_forces_positions[i] = 0;

if(my_rank == 0)
    printf("START\n\n");

send_to = (my_rank + 1) % comm_sz;
recv_from = (my_rank + comm_sz - 1) % comm_sz;

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
local_start = MPI_Wtime();

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count) private(i, phase)
{   
    for(i = 0; i < num_approximations; i++)
    {                                   
        for(phase = 0; phase < comm_sz; phase++)
        {
            #pragma omp single
            {
                test_start = MPI_Wtime();
                /* PERFORMANCE ISSUES START HERE */
                MPI_Sendrecv_replace(temp_forces_positions, local_num_particles * dimensions * 2, MPI_FLOAT, send_to, 0, recv_from, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);  
                /* PERFORMANCE ISSUES END HERE */
                test_finish = MPI_Wtime();
                test_elapsed += (test_finish - test_start);                                         
            }
        }       
    }
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
local_finish = MPI_Wtime(); 
local_elapsed = local_finish - local_start;
MPI_Reduce(&local_elapsed, &elapsed, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Reduce(&test_elapsed, &test_final, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(my_rank == 0)
{       
    printf("FINISHED\n\n");
    printf("Time taken total: %lf seconds\n", elapsed);
    printf("Time taken for communication: %lf seconds\n", test_final);
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}

Compile:
mmpicc -g -Wall -fopenmp -o n-body_issues n-body_issues.c

Execute:
mpiexec -n  ./n-body_issues

Run with at least 64 threads and 1000 approximations.

Expected performance:

With 4 processes, using 1, 2, or 3 threads words fine. Running on 4 threads results in a huge overhead.

Thanks

Comment: We can't possible help you based on that code snippet. If you really believe you narrowed down the performance issue, then craft a [mcve] and post it here - along with a detailed system description, performance observation as well as expectations. Otherwise you're on your own. Make sure to use a MPI aware performance analysis tool.

Comment: don't you need `#pragma omp barrier` before `#pragma omp single` ?
if the threads not executing `MPI_Sendrecv_replace()` are spinning, that might impact MPI performance. there is likely a runtime setting to change that behavior. also, which MPI library (and version) are you using, and what are the requested and provided thread levels by `MPI_Init_thread()` ?

Comment: I edited my original post with the information you requested. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't try the code, but by reading it, it appears that the initialization of MPI should request  at least a `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED` level of thread support, and that `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE` is definitely not enough. Just try that and check the value returned by `MPI_Init_thread()` for actually provided support. As it is now, your code is invalid.

Comment: or if you replace `#pragma omp single` with `#pragma omp master` (i assume you do need a barrier before that), `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED` could be enough

Comment: Gilles,

The only value supported by the MPI implementation I'm using is `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`. However, replacing  `#pragma omp single` with `#pragma omp master` reduced the overhead dramatically; do you know why this is? Also, there was a `#pragma omp barrier` already in at the end of the last method called just before `#pragma omp single` in my full-length code, so I should have added it explicitly in my example. 

Thanks a lot for the help.